# how to display a certain number of images from API - Kotlin - retrofit

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin, retrofit

i am calling data from API to display it to use but in my case i want to display the latest 4 images of the API, i don't want to call all of them

so what is the correct way to do this?

Here is my code:

Interface:

```
interface facebookInterface {

@GET(" ")

fun getServices(): Call<List<facebookData>>

companion object Factory {
    fun create(): facebookInterface {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("API_URL")
            .build()

        return retrofit.create(facebookInterface::class.java)
    }
}
}
```

Adapter:

```
class facebookAdapter(var countryList: List<facebookData>, var activity: MainActivity): RecyclerView.Adapter<facebookAdapter.ViewHolder>(){
lateinit var context: Context
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): facebookAdapter.ViewHolder {
    context = parent.context!!
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.facebook_list_item, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return countryList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: facebookAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.name.text = countryList[position].source
    holder.capital.text = countryList[position].imageLink



    Picasso.get()
        .load(countryList[position].imageUrl)
        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
        .into(holder.thumbnailUrl)




}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val name: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name)
    val capital: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_capital)
    val thumbnailUrl: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_flag)

}

}
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/list_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:contentPadding="8dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_constraint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/country_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/country_capital"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/country_name" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/country_flag"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Activity:

```
val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list_recycler4)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    val facebookInterface = facebookInterface.Factory.create()
    val facebok: Call<List<facebookData>> = facebookInterface.getServices()
    facebok.enqueue(object : Callback<List<facebookData>> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<facebookData>>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("xxxx", t.toString())
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<List<facebookData>>,
            response: Response<List<facebookData>>
        ) {
            Log.d("xxxx", response.body().toString())
            val list = response.body()!!
            recyclerView.adapter = facebookAdapter(list, this@MainActivity)
        }
    })
```

data class:

```
data class facebookData (
val  imageUrl : String,
val imageLink: String,
val source: String
    )
```

i am getting the data and i can see it on the device but is there a way to display only the latest 4 images from API?

and how to link the url of each image so the user can go to the url of each image

"English is not my mother tongue, i will explain more if you didn't understand me"

Comment: You should apply filter in your API, or you can just grab the latest 4 images and pass it into adapter

Comment: @Teo Thank you but can you show me an example of that? because i'm still new to Kotlin

Comment: What is the param that you want to get the latest 4 images? timestamp? show me your data class facebookData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Teo said, you are better of applying a filter directly to your API call, but if that is not possible, you can trim off the list you receive.
There are mainly two methods I can think of, that can get you what you want, first is to make a sublist and then assign the adapter as follows.

```kotlin
val trimmedList = if(list.size > 4){
            list.subList(fromIndex = 0, toIndex = 3)
        } else {
            list
        }
    recyclerView.adapter = facebookAdapter(trimmedList , this@MainActivity)
```

Second way to override the itemCount method inside the Recycler View Adapter, same logic shall apply there. It will be as follows.

```kotlin
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return if(countryList.size > 4) {
                4
            } else {
                countryList.size
            }
        }
```

For second part of your answer, I am adding the following code for your reference, but I still believe it is better for you to understand what is happening.

To open the url in browser, firstly you need a callback from your Adapter to your MainActivity.

Your adapter will be modified as the following.

```kotlin
class facebookAdapter(var countryList: List<facebookData>,
private val facebookAdapterCallback: FacebookAdapterCallback)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<facebookAdapter.ViewHolder>(){
    lateinit var context: Context
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): facebookAdapter.ViewHolder {
        context = parent.context!!
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.facebook_list_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return countryList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: facebookAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.name.text = countryList[position].source
        holder.capital.text = countryList[position].imageLink

        holder.thumbnailUrl.setOnClickListener {
            facebookAdapterCallback.onFacebookAdapterItemClick(countryList[position])
        }

        Picasso.get()
                .load(countryList[position].imageUrl)
                .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
                .into(holder.thumbnailUrl)
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val name: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name)
        val capital: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_capital)
        val thumbnailUrl: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_flag)
    }

    interface FacebookAdapterCallback{
        fun onFacebookAdapterItemClick(data: facebookData)
    }
}
```

Next we will have to modify your activity as follows to implement the above interface inside it

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), facebookAdapter.FacebookAdapterCallback {
    override fun onFacebookAdapterItemClick(data: facebookData) {
        openLinkInBrowser(this@MainActivity, data.imageLink)
    }

    fun openLinkInBrowser(context: Context, url: String) {
        try {
            val url = if (Uri.parse(url).scheme == null || !url.startsWith("https://") && !url.startsWith("http://")) {
                "https://$url"
            } else url
            val webPage: Uri = Uri.parse(url)
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webPage)
            if (intent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager) != null) {
                context.startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No App Available for this action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

I have also added a helper method to open the link in browser, it uses the default Android Intents and checks for apps available in which this action can be performed.
We also check if the URL has `http` or `https` appended else we add it.

While I have provided you the code, I would still recommend you to understand what is happening before doing it.

Comment: the 2nd method worked for me!, thank you very much

Comment: @user2 Glad to help, I realized I made a typo in the first method. I have fixed that too. Just in case you need it. You won't as such, but still.

Comment: it might be useful for others. is it possible to link an image from the same API?
because i'm getting the data and there is a URL for the post, how can i link each image to it is URL?

Comment: @user2 Could you clarify me more on what do you mean by link each image? As in do you want to open the URL for post in a browser when you click on each image?

Comment: exactly, i have updated my post here to include the "data class" because i'm calling posts from the API and i want if someone clicked the post will open the browser and redirect to the same post

Comment: @user2 Your data class has only three params? Can you clarify in which param are you getting the link of the post?

Comment: i'm getting it from "imageLink"

Comment: I have updated the answer for your query @user2 I recommend you go through it completely.

Comment: thank you again, you have been so helpful, is there anyway i can contact you? i would like to make an offer for you

Comment: @user2 You are welcome and I have updated my details on my StackOverflow Profile.